# JAVA memory use of extended class

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, extend

The situation:
I have parent class PARENT. 
Several classes which extends PATENT.

So question is: in memory is created as much copies of PARENT as there is CHILDS. Or in memory there is only one copy which is used by all CHILDS?

Comment: Please don't name it `PARENT`.

Comment: There is no parent in memory...

Comment: maybe I said bad. Each Child copies methods of PARENT?

Answer (score 4):

There is only one copy of each CHILD method, and of each PARENT method etc. Each CHILD object has a copy of each of its class's non-static fields, and of each of PARENT's non-static fields, and of each of Object's non-static fields.

Comment: so if I have method DO()  in PARENT and 10 childs which extends PARENT, so in memory I will have 10 copies of method DO()?

Comment: Object's non static fields? ;-)

Comment: @Edgar No, you will have one copy of DO(), unless one or more subclasses override it, in which case, of course, each overriding subclass will needs it own copy.

Comment: @assylias I don't think the current implementation of Object has any non-static fields, but the principle is important.

Answer (score 0):

Instance of a class consists of its parents fields and its own fields.

```
class A {
   int a;
}

class B extends A {
    int b;
}
```

instance of B is one instance (no A instance is created) which has 2 fields: int a and int b